# How to calculate key terms from a document with chi-squared test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I would like to extract key terms from documents with chi-squared test, thus I tried the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text  import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import  SelectKBest, chi2

Texts=["should schools have uniform","schools discipline","legalize marriage","marriage culture"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
term_doc=vectorizer.fit_transform(Texts)
ch2 = SelectKBest(chi2, "all")
X_train = ch2.fit_transform(term_doc)
print (ch2.scores_)
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

However, I do not have labels and when I run the above code I got:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Is there any way of using chi-squared test to extract most important words without having any labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chi-square statistic tests for dependence between two variables.  So it's not the right statistic for feature selection in an unsupervised (no labels) problem.

Depending on what your goal is in removing features, you could instead apply some feature preprocessing in your TfidfVectorizer.  You might threshold your vectorizer to discard very common words and very rare words.  For example, defining your vectorizer as:

```
TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.01, max_df=0.9)
```

will remove words that occur in fewer than 1% of documents or more than 90% of documents.

If your goal in removing unimportant features is to significantly reduce the dimensionality of the problem for subsequent analysis, you may also find dimensionality reduction techniques like [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD) to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help!... my objective is to extract key words that characterize that document in an unsupervised way... Indeed I tried with tfidf, so do you think those parameters are relevant for my purpose?

Comment: In that case, I think you are trying to solve the problem of keyword extraction. The ideas in this post will help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149327/automatic-keyword-extraction-using-cosine-similarities-as-features